# Understanding comand in run of docker

Tags: docker, shell

I have code which have dockerfile having this

```
FROM node:16-slim AS base
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install build-essential libcairo2-dev libpango1.0-dev libjpeg-dev libgif-dev librsvg2-dev

RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash xyz-deployer
WORKDIR /srv/app
RUN chmod -R g+rwX /srv/app
RUN yarn global add ts-node@^10.1.0
```

Can someone please tell me what is this doing in particular?

```
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash xyz-deployer
WORKDIR /srv/app
RUN chmod -R g+rwX /srv/app
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash xyz-deployer
```

creates a new user called `xyz-deployer` with a home directory and `/bin/bash` as the shell.

```
WORKDIR /srv/app
```

changes the working directory to `/srv/app`.

```
RUN chmod -R g+rwX /srv/app
```

sets all files in `/srv/app` to be group readable, writable and executable.

It doesn't make much sense in the context of the Dockerfile you've shown, but hopefully it helps.